# Using NSThread to solve waiting for image from URL on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsthread, autorelease, retain

So I have the following code in a method which I want to set a UIImageView image to that of one from an online source:

```
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(loadImage) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Then in the method called by the thread I have this:

```
- (void) loadImage
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:logoPath]; // logoPath is an NSString with path details
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    logoImage.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
}
```

This works great however I get many warnings within the Debugger Console along the lines of:

> 2010-05-10 14:30:14.052
>   ProjectTitle[2930:633f] ***
>   _NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x169d30 of class NSHTTPURLResponse
>   autoreleased with no pool in place -
>   just leaking

This occurs many times each time I call the new thread and then eventually, under no pattern, after calling a few of these threads I get the classic 'EXC_BAD_ACCESS' run-time error.

I understand that this is happening because I'm not retaining the object but how can I solve this with the code in 'loadImage' shown above?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create an autorelease pool for the thread otherwise objects which you do not explicitly release will not get released. See the [Apple Docs](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html), which essentially tell you to do the following:

```
- (void)myThreadMainRoutine
{
  NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init]; // Top-level pool

  // Do thread work here.

  [pool release];  // Release the objects in the pool.
}
```